# Rotating Product images so they look like there merging into a different view

Tags: javascript, image, animation, rotation

Imagine a page with three thumbnails on of different product views.  When you click on a view the main image div would quickly transition into the new view.

Say it was a shoe i was photographing and it had a sole view, top view and side view.

My question is is there any way of giving the illusion of a spin e.t.c from one view to another when its clicked on?  So not a straight change of image but a transition that works quickly to give the illusion of a morph almost.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to give an example of the transition you're looking for if you want a proper answer, but for now it seems like you're asking for the impossible.

Comment: If i had an example i wouldnt be asking the question.  But thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for sounds sort of like [Tweening](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inbetweening). One variation on this is [Morphing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphing) which provides a series of transitions from one still to another. [This site](http://www.morphthing.com/) has a tool that generates intermediate images and might be useful for *filling in the gaps* between the images you currently have. Then some standard form of fadeshow would give the appearance without incurring the computational overhead on every page load. [JavaMorph](http://code.google.com/p/javamorph/) is a Java applet that can do this inplace in realtime. Note: none of this was tested and no images were damaged in the making of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Peter is right - just use morphing: You can image this effect in 2 steps:

Morph from square to tiny rectangle (almost 1 width) - > replace content -> Morph again back to the same size.

Hope this helps :)